# Specify author as an organisation in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I cannot find an answer to this for Biblatex, only Bibtex.

I am using authoryear referencing.

I have several references where the author is a company. e.g. author = {Red Cloaks Ltd}

I want it to be printed as such in the bibliography, rather than Ltd, Red Cloaks, which is what I'm currently getting.

I've tried the Bibtex organization tag, but that means it doesn't print in the bibliography, and I've tried {"Red Cloaks Ltd"}, but that just prints as "Ltd, Red Cloaks", with the quotation mark

Comment: You seem to make a large distinction between the BibTex and biblatex ways of getting things done. That's not necessary here. Indeed, `author ={{Red Cloaks Ltd}}` is the correct solution for *both* bibtex and biblatex

Comment: The basic `.bib` file syntax is the same for BibTeX and `biblatex` (`biblatex` has some extension of the syntax in some cases and will only in rare cases not follow BibTeX behaviour). Even the semantics of fields and types are very similar in the most commonly used cases. So it is always a good idea to try solutions that are advertised as working for BibTeX also with `biblatex`. ...

Comment: ... The one big exception to this is probably that if you use Biber with `biblatex` (as most people do when they use `biblatex`) you can input non-ASCII chars as Unicode directly. You won't have to use the macro-escape that is necessary for BibTeX. (The macro escapes still work, but Unicode makes for an easier read and can avoid edge cases with dotless i and the like.)

Answer (score 0):

As I found the solution after much trying last night.
It needs to be author ={{Red Cloaks Ltd}}

Hopefully this will now pop up if someone else is trying to find the answer specifically for Biblatex!